# Challenging matrix sorting request?

Tags: matrix, algorithm, sorting, distance

I have an application in mind, and I need to do the following analysis, but am having a high degree of difficulty conceptualizing it in terms of syntax. I understand what I want, but cannot seem to pull through in terms of code. I have two n by n matrices, call them matrix A and matrix B. The sum of all the entries in each n by n matrix is defined to be 1 for all n. I want to be able to “convert” matrix A to matrix B. However, I want to do this with the following counter and by rearrangement with the following conditions (pretend here n is 3 but I want to generalize it to any n) :

Moving 1 unit horizontally or 1 unit vertically (no diagonal movement allowed) is equivalent to 1 point cost
So for example:

$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$
              $\qquad$to $\qquad$   $                       
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\              
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$

is 2 points cost because I moved the 1 two units down. Similarly,

$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$
              $\qquad$to $\qquad$   $                       
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$

is equivalent to 2 points because I had to go 1 unit left and 1 unit down. However,

$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$
              $\qquad$to $\qquad$   $                       
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0.8 & 0 \\
0.2 & 0 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$
Should be equivalent to 1 because you’re leaving 0.2 1 unit away, and 0.8  1 unit away (0.2*1+0.8*1). And then,

$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$
              $\qquad$to $\qquad$   $                       
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0.8 \\
0.2 & 0 & 0 \\              
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$
Should be equivalent to 1.8 because you are moving 0.2  1 unit away down and 0.8  2 units away right (0.2*1+0.8*2). However, I may not always have just a “1” that needs to be doled out everywhere, I could have matrices like:

$\begin{matrix}
0.2 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
0 & 0.3 & 0 \\              
0.04 & 0.06 & 0.2 \\
\end{matrix}$
              $\qquad$to $\qquad$   $                       
\begin{matrix}
0.1 & 0.42 & 0.1 \\
0.08 & 0.02 & 0.05 \\              
0.2 & 0 & 0.03 \\
\end{matrix}
$

And I will need to optimize in terms of points. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the application of this?

Comment: Is there a bound for *n*? Also, neither of your two final examples sum to 1 as claimed in preamble - so what's the story?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the heads up. I took the tour, and I am excited to be a part of this community.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. It has to do with analyzing 2 physical distributions. I can't get into too much of the specifics because I will be needing to share this with a mentor for an idea. Unfortunately, out of the many ways of analyzing 2 distributions, this specific method is needed.

Comment: @ciao Ciao, thank you for your response. Capping "n" at 40 should be more than enough for me. Ciao, sorry, I was filling in arbitrary numbers in my head. The entries should be 1.

Comment: Without more details of this super-secret process that must be used, beats me - exhaustive search is out of the question since even the simple *n*=3 case has ~10^21 ways to be "looked at". I'm going to +1 in any case, and if requirements are relaxed and / or details/justifications for *this method required* are added it might help readers.

Comment: Well, it's not super secret. Because there are academic politics involved, I'll let more cats out of the bag, but not too many. It's just a way of taking multiple probability distributions generated by an engineered machine, and ranking them in terms of similarity based on the "points" it costs. One can imagine that if I have A, B, and C..and A takes 2.3 points to convert to B, but it takes 5.7 points to convert to C, A is more similar than B. I have to use this method though and not other metrics unfortunately. 

EDIT: How did you get 10^21?

Comment: @MikeShawn I think this is interesting but I suspect you may have better luck posting on [Math.SE] to get help with the algorithm to use, then come back for implementation help if needed.

Comment: Further reading: [transportation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics))

Comment: This is similar to (though not identical to) the Edit distance between two vectors. The major difference is that you want to apply to matrices. Since the edit distance is calculated by a dynamic program, there's a good chance that this would have to be the way to calculate your distance function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: Subtract matrix A from matrix B. Use greedy approach to move each positive to closest negative to zero them both. Obviously this will require a bit of coding.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry, there might be a lack of understanding on my part. After I subtract matrix A from Matrix B, what positive and negatives am I rearranging and what should I get out of it?

Comment: Making B identical to A by the moves you describe is the same as making B-A equal to 0. For each negative therein, move as much of the nearest positive as needed to make it zero. If that positive is too small to make it zero, move it all and proceed to next nearest positive, etc.

Comment: @MikeShawn: Sorry for delay in reply - that 10^21 is a BOTE: for each entry, there are 2^8-1 subsets to consider adjusting from, that value ^9 for all combinations of those subsets. Clearly that's an upper bound, but even with MUCH trimming, you're left with something big. I think the graph solution is plausible (I upvoted), but I found in prior use of the function it's a bit slow/buggy (not the post, the MMA function). Daniels idea is similar to mine, though I think there's more to the optimization than just picking nearest positive + next nearest...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it's too long for a comment.  It doesn't completely work, but perhaps it might inspire other answers.

The idea is to use graph theory and flows.  I shall just look at the 3x3 case. First we construct a graph of 9 source nodes and 9 sink nodes.  The source nodes flow costlessly straight into the sink nodes, and the sink nodes can flow around in the grid.

```
e = {
  1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2,
  1 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 2, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 3,
  4 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 5,
  4 -> 7, 7 -> 4, 5 -> 8, 8 -> 5, 6 -> 9, 9 -> 6,
  7 -> 8, 8 -> 7, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 8
  };

g = Graph[Range@18, Table[v -> (9 + v), {v, 9}] ~Join~ (e /. k_Integer :> 9 + k),
  EdgeCost -> (ConstantArray[0, 9]~Join~ConstantArray[1, 24]), VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: graph]

Now we can do:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, {
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0,

  0, 0, -0.8,
  -0.2, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0
  }]
```

> `1.8`

As required.  Note how we use positive values for the first matrix and negative values for the second.  There are probably other graphs that might do the same job.

If we try the last example:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, {
   20, 10, 10,
   0, 30, 0,
   4, 6, 20,

   -10, -42, -10,
   -8, -2, -5,
   -20, 0, -3
   }/100]
```

It fails (just repeats the input).  However it we put a slight fudge in there:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, {
   20, 10, 10,
   0, 30, 0.000001,
   4, 6, 20,

   -10, -42, -10,
   -8, -2, -5,
   -20, 0, -3
   }/100]
```

> `0.75`

We get an answer.  This is on version 9 - maybe it works better on 10?  We can also get a graphical representation of it:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[g, {
   20, 10, 10,
   0, 30, 0.000001,
   4, 6, 20,

   -10, -42, -10,
   -8, -2, -5,
   -20, 0, -3
   }/100, "FlowGraph"]
```

[image: flow]

Comment: Thank you very much, you are truly phenomenal!